# Do I repay Social Security Disability Insurance (SSDI) if I suddenly have income and assets

Tags: united-states, social-security, repayment

I have four chronic disabling diseases and have received Social Security Disability Insurance (SSDI)  for 10 years.

If I suddenly own a home and income property, must I repay social security? If so,  how would I proceed?  Note: I have received nothing. This is hypothetical.

Comment: Please include country tag

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of insurance, which causes some confusion.

Social Security Disability Insurance (which you indicate you have) is insurance you can receive benefit from if you earn enough "work credits" (payroll taxes) prior to your disability onset. It is *not* a needs-based program.

Supplemental Security Income *is a need-based program* which does not consider your work history. To qualify for this, your total assets need to be lower than some threshold and your family income also below some threshold.

If you inherit a home, or money, I doubt this would jeopardize your SSDI qualification, since your qualification was based on a disabling condition and work history. If you inherit an income property, which you manage (i.e. you become a landlord), this may jeopardize your claim that you are unable to work. Even if you are not making an "income" as the landlord, but the work your are performing is deemed to have some "value" this too could jeopardize your claim.

All of this can be very complicated, and there are some excellent references on the web including SSA website, and some other related websites.

Finally, if you become able to work while on SSDI, your benefit may/will end depending on the level of work you are able to perform. But just because you are able to work again does not mean you need to repay past benefits received (assuming your condition has not been falsified).

Your local social security office, or the social security main office both offer telephone support and can also answer questions regarding your concern.

Here are a couple relevant links:

- http://www.disabilitysecrets.com/page5-13.html
- http://www.disabilitysecrets.com/resources/disability/can-i-start-a-small-business-and-still-
- http://www.disability-benefits-help.org/blog/inheritance-ssdi

Comment: So, OP needs to not claim he's an active landlord? This is a claim that must be made on Sch E, and would preclude him from taking losses. Which, if the property runs at a profit, is no issue. He should hire a management company, and document his lack of physical work.